# Problem Identiying why : ValueError: infinity or too large AFTER normalization

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scale, infinite

I have a data set that I normalize first, the dropping the na, now, I try df[col] = preprocessing.scale(df[col].values) and here i get the error : ValueError: Input contains infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Here are the steps I had done :

1- Made sure the data table (pandas) Has no NAN by dropping nan
2- normalize the values using pct_change
3- dropping na right after calling pct_change

and then trying the scale function and getting the error

here is the code snippet :

from main call :

```html
dataset = f"./Data/Original/{RATIO_TO_PREDICT}.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(dataset)
df.set_index("Timestamp", inplace = True)

#calculate volume candle type 1

#calculate volume candle type 2

#df['VC1_Future'] = df["VC1"].shift(-FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT)
#df['VC1_Target'] = list(map(classify,df["VC1"], df["VC1_Future"]))

#df['VC2_Future'] = df["VC2"].shift(-FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT)
#df['VC2_Target'] = list(map(classify,df["VC2"], df["VC2_Future"]))

df.fillna(method="ffill", inplace = True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

df['Price_Future'] = df["Close"].shift(-FUTURE_PERIOD_PREDICT) # We go N number of time to the future, get that value and put it in this row's FUTURE PRICE value
df['Price_Target'] = list(map(classify,df["Close"], df["Price_Future"])) 
# Now we compare the current price with that future price to see if we went up, down or none, here we use the 0.015 or 1.5% spread to make sure we pass commision

# Now we want to separate part of the data for training and another part for testing
times = sorted(df.index.values)
last_5pct = times[-int(0.1 * len(times))]


# We get the final columns we want, making sure we are not including any of the High, Low, and Open values. Remember that Price Target is last. That is OUR GOAL !!!
#dfs = df[["Close", "Volume", "Price_Future", "Price_Target"]]#, "VC1", "VC2", "VC1_Future", "VC2_Future", "VC1_Target", "VC2_Target", "Price_Future", "Price_Target"]]


# We finally separate the data into two different lists
validation_df = df[(df.index >= last_5pct)]
training_df = df[(df.index < last_5pct)]

# We save each list into a file so that we don't need to make this process walk through again unless A) we get new data B) we loose previous data on hard drive
Message(name)
print(len(df), len(training_df), len(validation_df))
Message(len(df))
#training_df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(np.isfinite(training_df).all())

print('')

#validation_df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(np.isfinite(validation_df).all())


Train_X, Train_Y = preprocess(training_df)
```

Now, when it comes to the function, here is the start :

```html
def preprocess(df) :
    df.drop('Price_Future', 1)
    #df.drop('VC1_Future', 1)
    #df.drop('VC2_Future', 1)
    for col in df.columns:
        if col != "Price_Target" and col != "VC1_Target" and col != "VC2_Target":
            df[col] = df[col].pct_change() # gets the percent change, other than the volume, the data now should sit between -1 and 1, the formula : (value[i] / value[i-1]) - 1
            df.dropna(inplace=True)
            df[col] = preprocessing.scale(df[col].values)
```

When I call the main, as you may noticed, I'm checking for nan, the result :

```html
Open             True
High             True
Low              True
Close            True
Volume           True
Price_Future    False
Price_Target     True
dtype: bool
```

and right at the start of the function I'm dropping the Price_Future column, so, WHY am I getting this error at the scaling line?

Also, the above code cause lots of warnings :

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

But I'm new to python and all of this stuff so I don't know how to fix the code on the function.

Someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post sample data or the csv to a dropbox? The error is pretty straightforward as it means even after normalization you have values that are too large to process. Can't tell where though without some data

Comment: ouch, it really shouldn't it's a normal market price data series, even tried dropping the volume data, other than that, the remaining is open,high,low,close values, can't imagine why they would be out of shape

Comment: No offense but we cannot debut a data problem without data. Can you post the csv someone so we can test the script?

Comment: well, these may help  http://prntscr.com/nasw2b  http://prntscr.com/naswav  http://prntscr.com/nasweg

Comment: Runnable code blocks are for HTML/CSS/JavaScript only. Do not use them for Python.

Comment: sorry, new to the site, tried code first but was failing. not sure why

Comment: You need to edit your question to fix the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

OUCH, found the main issue ;

df[col] = preprocessing.scale(df[col].values)

is wrong

df[col] = preprocessing.scale(df[col])

Notice the lack of .values in the scale call !!!

But please someone help me with those warning messages.